# right click menu doesn't show up in perforce

Tags: perforce

I am working via VPN network and connected to perforce. Sometimes when I right click on the top node under 'workspace' tab next to 'depot' the drop down right menu doesn't show up. When this happens often the File > Action drown down main manu is also grayed out. This eventually comes back to life and so does the right click menu but right now I am waiting for more than an hour but the right click menu is still now showing. Has anyone seen this issue and is there a fix for it?

Comment: Is your VPN connection dropping out?  Do you have connectivity to your Perforce server from the command line?

Comment: @p4-randall No my VPN connection is solid and I am using high internet of the order of 20 MBPS so I am sure connection or speed is not an issue.